# Fontspec {cannot-use-pdftex}

Tags: compilation-error

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[francais]{babel}
sepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{carlito}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\date{}
\definecolor{noir}{rgb}{.09,.09,.09}
\definecolor{blanc}{rgb}{.91,.91,.91}
\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{.91,.09,.09}
\definecolor{vert}{HTML}{9ECE63}
\definecolor{bleu}{rgb}{.09,.09,.91}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=-bleu}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=bleu}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blanc,bg=vert!55!noir}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=noir!90!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=rouge!55!noir,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=noir!90!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=-rouge!45!blanc,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=noir!90!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=vert}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=white,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=white,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=,fg=bleu!50!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=,fg=-vert}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{use=item,bg=,fg=item.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=titlelike, bg=titlelike.bg, fg=titlelike.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{use=titlelike, fg=titlelike.fg, bg=titlelike.bg}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{use=block title, bg=block title.bg}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{fg=blanc,bg=blanc}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\bf\fontsize{18}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\bf\fontsize{11}{2}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\bf\fontsize{26}{16}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{26}{12}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\fontsize{21}{8}\selectfont}
\setbeamertemplate{title}{
    \vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{center}
        \insettitle
\end{center}
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\insertframetitle \vspace*{0.1cm}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.25cm,text margin right=2cm}
\definecolor{MyBackground}{rgb}{0.21176    0.21176    0.21176}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MyBackground}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theoreme}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}
\newtheorem{rqs}{Remarques}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Exemple}
\newtheorem{exemple}{Exemples}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{corollaire}{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemme}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\displaystyle \sum}
\newcommand{\Int}{\displaystyle \int}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lf{\left}
\def\hs{\hspace{0.5cm}}
\def\dint{\displaystyle\int}
\def\dlim{\displaystyle\lim}
\def\dsup{\displaystyle\sup}
\def\dmin{\displaystyle\min}
\def\dmax{\displaystyle\max}
\def\dinf{\displaystyle\inf}
\def\Proof{\noindent{\bf Proof}\quad}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\def \ud{\text{d} }
\newcommand{\cadre}[1]{\begin{center}\shadowbox{$#1$}\end{center}}
\newcommand{\tran}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
\newcommand{\transpose}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
\newcommand{\trans}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
\newcommand{\transp}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
\newcommand{\pmatrice}[1]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\amatrice}[1]{\left[\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}\right]}
\newcommand{\matrice}[1]{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}}
\newcommand{\system}[1]{\left\{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}\right.}
\newcommand{\GL}[2]{\rm{GL}_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
\newcommand{\SL}[2]{\rm{SL}_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
\newcommand{\Mc}[2]{\mathcal M_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
\newcommand{\Mnp}[3]{\mathcal M_{#1,#2}\left( \mathbb #3\right)}
\newcommand{\Mn}[2]{\mathcal M_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
\def \MnC {\mathcal M_n (\mathbb C)}
\def \MnR {\mathcal M_n (\mathbb R)}
\def \MnK {\mathcal M_n (\mathbb K)}
\def \com {\rm {com }}
\newcommand{\colmat}[2]{#2_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Mat}[2] {\ensuremath{\underset{#1}{\rm Mat}}\left(#2\right)}
\newcommand{\matc}[3]{#2=\left( #3_{ij}\right)_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant #1}}
\newcommand{\matnp}[3]{\left( #3_{ij}\right)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant #1\atop 1\leqslant j\leqslant #2}}
\newcommand{\seveng}[1]{{\rm Vect}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\linnpk}[3]{\mathcal L\left({#3}^{#1},{#3}^{#2}\right)}
\newcommand{\lin}[2]{\mathcal L\left({#1},{#2}\right)}
\def \im {\mbox{Im}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} \allowdisplaybreaks
\DeclareMathOperator{\divg }{div}

% Alphabet grec
\renewcommand{\a}{\alpha}\renewcommand{\b}{\beta}\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}\newcommand{\G}{\Gamma}\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}\newcommand{\z}{\zeta} \newcommand{\y}{\eta}\renewcommand{\th}{\theta}\newcommand{\Th}{\Theta}\renewcommand{\i}{\iota}\renewcommand{\k}{\kappa}\newcommand{\vk}{\varkappa}\renewcommand{\l}{\lambda}\renewcommand{\L}{\Lambda}\newcommand{\m}{\mu}\newcommand{\n}{\nu}\newcommand{\x}{\xi}\newcommand{\X}{\Xi}\newcommand{\s}{\sigma}\renewcommand{\SS}{\Sigma}\renewcommand{\t}{\tau}\newcommand{\f}{\varphi}\newcommand{\vf}{\phi}\newcommand{\h}{\chi}\newcommand{\p}{\psi}\renewcommand{\P}{\Psi}\renewcommand{\o}{\omega}\renewcommand{\O}{\Omega}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=2}



\begin{document}

\title[SÃ©ries entiÃ¨res]
\subtitle{Premiers exemples}
\author[ MSAAD]{}
\institute[Institut]{}
\date[11/2019]{}
\maketitle



\begin{frame}


\begin{frame}

\frametitle{SÃ©ries entiÃ¨res}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf {\textcolor {vert}{DÃ©finition : }}
On appelle sÃ©rie entiÃ¨re, toute sÃ©rie de fonctions de la forme $\displaystyle\sum a_nz^n$ oÃ¹ $(a_n)_n\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lemme d'Abel}

\textbf {\textcolor {vert}{Proposition : }}
Soit $\sum a_nz^n$ une sÃ©rie entiÃ¨re et $z_0\mathbb{C}$ tel que la suite $(a_n)_n$ soit bornÃ©e, alors la sÃ©rie $\sum a_nz^n$ converge pour tout nombre complexe $z$ tel que
$\vert z\vert \< \vert z_0\vert$
\end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lemme d'Abel }
\textbf {\textcolor {vert}{Proposition : }}
Soit $\sum a_nz^n$ une sÃ©rie entiÃ¨re et $z_0\mathbb{C}$ tel que la suite $(a_n)_n$ soit bornÃ©e, alors la sÃ©rie $\sum a_nz^n$ converge pour tout nombre complexe $z$ tel que
$\vert z\vert \< \vert z_0\vert$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whatever your problem is: shorten your code.

Comment: `polyglossia` and `fontspec` can only be used with the Unicode engines LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. They can not be used with pdfLaTeX. The preamble looks as though it was designed for XeLaTeX (`xltxtra`), but then it also contains `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` which is pretty much pointless for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, because they want UTF-8-encoded files. (As an aside the file encoding seems to be a bit off - at least as posted here: `SÃ©ries entiÃ¨res` doesn't appear to be what you want.) But Urlike is right: The code is much too long for anyone to be happy to trawl through.

Comment: It would appear that you're trying to compile the document with pdfLaTeX, even though some of the packages loaded by your document indicate that you should be compiling it with XeLaTeX. If that's the case, your document has no business loading `fontenc`. The fragment `sepackage{xltxtra}` should probably be deleted. Also, don't load both `polyglossia` and `babel` -- chose one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: Aside: the instruction `\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}` is almost certainly inappropriate. You may want to replace it with `\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}`.

Comment: See for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/The_TeX_family_tree:_LaTeX,_pdfTeX,_XeTeX,_LuaTeX_and_ConTeXt for some background information.

Comment: Thank you very much